# CSS or SASS selector that only uses uppercase letters

Tags: html, css, angularjs, sass

So, I stumbled across something like this:

```
SM\:BUTTON {
    [some props];
}
```

and I've never seen something like this before. What does it do?

The file type is .scss and apparently it's also SASS syntax. However, if that's the case then it could also be plain CSS. Since the selector selects an angular directive i.e.

```
<sm:button class="..."></sm:button>
```

I thought it might have something to do with escaping the colon but I looked that up and the `\:` does the trick already. So, I'm pretty much clueless here.

Comment: HTML tags are case-insensitive.  That doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS selectors like tags, classes and IDs are generally **not** case-sensitive. [See the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#casesens):

> All Selectors syntax is case-insensitive within the ASCII range (i.e.
>   [a-z] and [A-Z] are equivalent), except for parts that are not under
>   the control of Selectors. The case sensitivity of document language
>   element names, attribute names, and attribute values in selectors
>   depends on the document language. For example, in HTML, element names
>   are case-insensitive, but in XML, they are case-sensitive.